# Unity3d blender fbx file gun is apart

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

hello i exporting a blender.fbx file into my assets folder in unity and it was working perfectly and i positioned it in front of the camera but when i play it the gun looks like its been taken apart whats going on?!if this helps i separated some parts so i could use it for animation cause it looks like all the animation parts are separate is this a unity thing or a blender thing?

http://www.flickr.com/photos/87198010@N07/7985274177/in/photostream

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. It could be that your animation is incorrect.. remove animation to test..
2. The position of the child objects, barrel and trigger, may be incorrect in relationship to the parent.. I don't know for a fact, just a few thinks that come to mind.

Let us know when you find out.

Comment: well at the moment the i grouped the parts the are needed for animation but i have not at started animating them so i might look at option 2 :)

Comment: it looks ok when i import it into unity it just when i play the game thats when it looks apart

Answer (score 0):

When you load a mesh into unity, unity will as a standard add an animation module to it, even if you don't have any animations yet. this may be what is making the gun bug.
If there is an animation component on it, remove said component and try again.

Also it might be that different parts of the gun are at different scales or rotations, before you export from blender click  and click 'apply rotation and scale', and then you export.